# Parallelize function which will count all vectors with sum equal of vector elements and elements not bigger of k

Tags: c, cuda

I want to parallelize a function in CUDA C which will count all vectors with sum equal of vector elements and elements not bigger than k. For example if the number of vector elements n is 5, sum=10 and k=3 than, the number of vectors who satisfy this condition is 101. I've already made this function in CUDA C but the problem is when the number of blocks and threads are bigger than 1. I know that the problem is in `for` cycles and I should change it but I don't know from where to start. When I am calling the function with blocks and threads equal to one than the function is working on classic way and everything is good but in this case the function is not parallelized.

The source code of the program is:

```
//function that count number of vectors
__device__ void count(int *vector, int *total, int n, int s)
{
 int i,sum=0;
 for(i=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;i<n;i+=blockDim.x*gridDim.x)
 {    
   sum+=vector[i];
   __syncthreads();
 }
 if(sum==s)
 {  
   total[0]=total[0]+1;
 }
}

//main function
__global__ void computeVectors(int *vector, int n, int kk, int s, int *total)
{
 int k=0;
 int j,i,next;

 while(1)
 {
  //this is the problem, in for cycle
  for(j=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x; j<=kk; j+=blockDim.x*gridDim.x)
  {
   vector[k]=j;
   count(vector, total, n, s);
   __syncthreads();
  }
  for(i=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x; i<n; i+=blockDim.x*gridDim.x)
  {

   if(vector[i]<kk)
      break;
  }  
  next=i;
  vector[next]++;
  for(i=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x; i<sledno; i+=blockDim.x*gridDim.x)
  {
   vector[i]=0;
   __syncthreads();
  }
  k=0;
  if(next>=n)
    break;
 }
}

int main()
{
  cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;

  int n,k,sum;
  int counter=0;

  printf("Enter the length of vector n=");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("Enter the max value of vector elements k=");
  scanf("%d",&k);
  printf("Enter the sum of vector elements sum=");
  scanf("%d",&sum);

  //initial vector with length n
  int *vec_h, *vec_d;
  size_t sizevec=n*sizeof(int);
  vec_h=(int *)malloc(sizevec);
  cudaMalloc((void **) &vec_d, sizevec);

  for(counter=0; counter<n; counter++)
  {
   vec_h[counter]=0;
  }
  cudaMemcpy(vec_d, vec_h, sizevec, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  int *total_h, *total_d;
  size_t size=1*sizeof(int);
  total_h=(int *)malloc(size);
  cudaMalloc((void **) &total_d, size);
  total_h[0]=0;
  cudaMemcpy(total_d, total_h, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  //calling the main function
  computeVectors<<<1, 1>>>(vec_d, n, k, sum, total_d);

  cudaThreadSynchronize(); 

  err = cudaGetLastError();
  if (err != cudaSuccess)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  cudaMemcpy(total_h, total_d, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  printf("Number of vectors that satisfy condition is %d\n", total_h[0]);

  free(vec_h); 
  cudaFree(vec_d);

  free(total_h); 
  cudaFree(total_d);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume the vector elements can range from 0 to `k`, and `k` is expected to be a positive number?  Since you're calling the kernel with 1 threadblock of 1 thread, you haven't really parallelized anything at all.  You're simply running serial code.  Have you made any attempts to parallelize at all?  Do you even have a strategy?  For example, if you have multiple threads, what would you have each thread do? (Perhaps an individual pattern test?)  What might each block be responsible for?  (Perhaps a segment of the overall space to test?)

Comment: Yes, k is positive number, I know that when number of blocks and threads is 1 than the code is running serial. How to use threads for pattern test?

Comment: The space to test is all of the vectors of length `n`, where each vector element has `k`+1 possible values.  Therefore, using a naive brute-force approach, there are (k+1)^n possible vectors to test.  One approach would be to have each thread do *all* the work (vector generation, sum computation, sum test) to test a single vector, and then have the entire grid loop through the entire space of (k+1)^n vectors.  For the vectors that tested correctly, you could use an atomic operation at the end of each thread to update the `count` value.  This would be for (k+1)^n that fits in `unsigned long`.

Comment: So you suggest to generate all possible vector combinations and after generating to use one thread for one combinations and check it is vector satisfy the condition?

Comment: It's one possible approach. Not particularly clever, but it has the benefit that it should be easy to try because it would be similar to the way you would write the code for a naive CPU serial implementation.  And I wouldn't generate the vectors up front -- you'll run out of space for large problems.  I would have each thread generate it's unique vector on the fly, using an algorithm based on the thread index (`int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;`) This way you only need enough storage for a grid's worth of vectors at a time.

Comment: Can you give me some example how to use thread index for one unique vector?

Comment: @Dragon: Such an algorithm is called an [unranking](http://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~ruskey/Publications/RankPerm/RankPerm.html) function. See also [1](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~gptesler/184a/slides/rank_s13-handout.pdf), [2](https://oeis.org/wiki/Ranking_and_unranking_functions).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example brute-force program to enumerate all the possible vectors, and then test the sum of each vector to see if it matches the desired sum.

- Assume `n`= length of vector in "digits"
- Assume each vector "digit" is represented by an `unsigned` quantity
- Assume `k`=maximum "digit" value + 1
- The size of the vector space is given by `k`^`n`
- Divide this space into contiguous groups of vectors to be processed by each thread: (`k`^`n`)/grid_size
- generate the starting vector for each thread (i.e. the starting vector in each group)
- Each thread then loops through testing the vector sum and incrementing the count if necessary, and then "incrementing" the vector, until each thread has processed it's assigned contiguous group of vectors

The program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_N 12
#define nTPB 256
#define GRIDSIZE (32*nTPB)


#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)


// thrust code is to quickly prototype a CPU based
// method for verification
int increment(thrust::host_vector<unsigned> &data, unsigned max){
  int pos = 0;
  int done = 0;
  int finished = 0;

  while(!done){
    data[pos]++;
    if (data[pos] >= max) {
      data[pos] = 0;
      pos++;
      if (pos >= data.size()){
        done = 1;
        finished = 1;
        }
      }
    else done = 1;
  }
  return finished;
}

__constant__ unsigned long powers[MAX_N];

__device__ unsigned vec_sum(unsigned *vector, int size){
  unsigned sum = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<size; i++) sum += vector[(i*nTPB)];
  return sum;
}

__device__ void create_vector(unsigned long index, unsigned *vector, int size){
  unsigned long residual = index;
  unsigned pos = size;
  while ((residual > 0) && (pos > 0)){
    unsigned long temp = residual/powers[pos-1];
    vector[(pos-1)*nTPB] = temp;
    residual -= temp*powers[pos-1];
    pos--;
    }
  while (pos>0) {
   vector[(pos-1)*nTPB] = 0;
   pos--;
   }
}
__device__ void increment_vector(unsigned *vector, int size, int k){
  int pos = 0;
  int done = 0;

  while(!done){
    vector[(pos*nTPB)]++;
    if (vector[pos*nTPB] >= k) {
      vector[pos*nTPB] = 0;
      pos++;
      if (pos >= size){
        done = 1;
        }
      }
    else done = 1;
  }
}

__global__ void find_vector_match(unsigned long long int *count, int k, int n, unsigned sum){
  __shared__ unsigned vecs[MAX_N *nTPB];
  unsigned *vec = &(vecs[threadIdx.x]);
  unsigned long idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (idx < (k*powers[n-1])){
    unsigned long vec_count = 0;
    unsigned long vecs_per_thread = (k*powers[n-1])/(gridDim.x*blockDim.x);
    vecs_per_thread++;
    unsigned long vec_num = idx*vecs_per_thread;
    create_vector((vec_num), vec, n);
    while ((vec_count < vecs_per_thread) && (vec_num < (k*powers[n-1]))){
      if (vec_sum(vec, n) == sum) atomicAdd(count, 1UL);
      increment_vector(vec, n, k);
      vec_count++;
      vec_num++;
      }
   }
}

int main(){

// calculate on CPU first for verification
  struct timeval t1, t2, t3;
  int n, k, sum;
  printf("Enter the length of vector (maximum: %d) n=", MAX_N);
  scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("Enter the max value of vector elements k=");
  scanf("%d",&k);
  printf("Enter the sum of vector elements sum=");
  scanf("%d",&sum);
  int count = 0;
  gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
  k++;

  thrust::host_vector<unsigned> test(n);
  thrust::fill(test.begin(), test.end(), 0);
  int finished = 0;
  do{
    if (thrust::reduce(test.begin(), test.end()) == sum) count++;
    finished = increment(test, k);
    }
    while (!finished);
  gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
  printf("CPU count = %d, in %d seconds\n", count, t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec);
  unsigned long h_powers[MAX_N];
  h_powers[0] = 1;
  if (n < MAX_N)
    for (int i = 1; i<n; i++) h_powers[i] = h_powers[i-1]*k;
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(powers, h_powers, MAX_N*sizeof(unsigned long));
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpyToSymbolfail");
  unsigned long long int *h_count, *d_count;
  h_count = (unsigned long long int *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long long int));
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_count, sizeof(unsigned long long int));
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc fail");
  *h_count = 0;
  cudaMemcpy(d_count, h_count, sizeof(unsigned long long int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy H2D fail");
  find_vector_match<<<(GRIDSIZE + nTPB -1)/nTPB, nTPB>>>(d_count, k, n, sum);
  cudaMemcpy(h_count, d_count, sizeof(unsigned long long int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy D2H fail");
  gettimeofday(&t3, NULL);
  printf("GPU count = %d, in %d seconds\n", *h_count, t3.tv_sec - t2.tv_sec);

  return 0;
}
```

compile with:

```
$ nvcc -O3 -arch=sm_20 -o t260 t260.cu
```

sample output:

```
$ ./t260
Enter the length of vector (maximum: 12) n=2
Enter the max value of vector elements k=3
Enter the sum of vector elements sum=4
CPU count = 3, in 0 seconds
GPU count = 3, in 0 seconds
$ ./t260
Enter the length of vector (maximum: 12) n=5
Enter the max value of vector elements k=3
Enter the sum of vector elements sum=10
CPU count = 101, in 0 seconds
GPU count = 101, in 0 seconds
$ ./t260
Enter the length of vector (maximum: 12) n=9
Enter the max value of vector elements k=9
Enter the sum of vector elements sum=20
CPU count = 2714319, in 12 seconds
GPU count = 2714319, in 1 seconds
$ ./t260
Enter the length of vector (maximum: 12) n=10
Enter the max value of vector elements k=9
Enter the sum of vector elements sum=20
CPU count = 9091270, in 123 seconds
GPU count = 9091270, in 4 seconds
```

So for large problem sizes, the naive brute-force GPU code appears to be about 30x faster than the naive brute-force single-threaded CPU code. (... on my particular machine setup:  CPU = Xeon X5560, GPU = Quadro5000, CentOS 5.5, CUDA 5.0)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is __*syncthreads()*. For a __*syncthreads()* to work properly, all the threads inside the block should be able to reach it otherwise some threads wait forever and your program doesn't get out.
In your program, execution of __*syncthreads()* in some parts is conditional. That's the reason why your program doesn't work with more than one thread in one block.

Comment: I removed __syncthreads() but it's same, it's not working with more than one thread.

Answer (score 0):

As Robert said in comments, if you want to generate all (k+1)^n permutations on GPU and test them, you can think of some GPU kernel like this:

```
__device__ int count;  //global variable must be initialized to zero before kernel call
__global__ void perm_generator(int k, int n, int sum) {
   int tid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
   int id = tid;
   int mysum = 0;
   for ( int i = n; i > 1; i-- ) { //all n-1 vector elements
     mysum += (id % (k+1));
     id /= (k+1);
   }
   mysum += id; //last element
   if ( mysum == sum ) atomicAdd( &count, 1 );
}
```

The kernel should be called with exactly (k+1)^n threads. If you happen to call your kernel with more threads (simply because rule of thumb that block dimension should be multiple of 32), you need to check value of **tid** inside your kernel beforehand.
Also, **cudaThreadSynchronize()** is deprecated. Use **cudaDeviceSynchronize()** instead.

Comment: This method works too, and I tested it and compared it to my approach.  It's quite a bit slower than my code (about 8x slower on my "large" problem), probably because to generate each vector, you require `n`-1 modulo operations and `n`-1 division operations.  On average, my code requires approximately a single addition operation to generate each vector, regardless of `n`.

Comment: Yes you've devised your algorithm wisely.