# Is there any problems we can solve using CPU faster rather than using GPU?

Tags: gpu, cpu

Recently I always hear that GPU is very powerful in computing, and now a question occurs in my mind:
Is there any problems we can solve using CPU faster rather than using GPU?

Can you give me some examples?

Comment: Typically, yes: almost all the things we are continuing to do on the CPU instead of the GPU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"GPU is very powerful in computing!" YES!*

But GPU is NOT a "faster CPU". You can summarize this way:

- CPU has a few strong cores (strong when compared to GPU).
- GPU has a lot of weak cores (weak when compared to CPU).

**I am considering here GPU as being [GPGPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gpgpu). They are actualy  a little bit different because of graphics pipeline, but the idea is the same! The shaders work like what I explain down here.**

GPU is basically designed to compute "parallelizable algorithms". It means algorithms that really need to open hundreds, thousands or even millions of threads to solve some determined task!

Some very dummy examples:

**Non parallelizable algorithm (CPU):**

```
unsigned int X = 0;
unsigned int data[ 10000 ];

fillDataFromSomeWhereWithSomething( data );

for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 10000; i++ )
{
    X += data[ i ] * data[ i ];
}
```

For every cycle of the loop , `X` depends on the previous value of `X`. So there is no sense for us to open threads for this! There's only one single flow! One must use CPU for this!

**Parallelizable algorithm (GPU):**

```
int X[ 10000 ] = { 0 };
unsigned int data[ 10000 ];

fillDataFromSomeWhereWithSomething( data );

for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 10000; i++ )
{
    X[ i ] = data[ i ] * data[ i ];
}
```

Here, for every value of `X[ ? ]`, the result is straightforward dependent on `i` only. **The cycles are independent!** So, instead of loop over 10000. You can use a GPU to open 10000 threads for you and do all the cycles in parallel.

**How it works?**

You upload the input `data` from CPU to GPU. Then you tell your GPU to execute 10000 threads in a small program called kernel. Every kernel has it's own output. The kernel will ony compute:

```
X_i = data[ i ] * data[ i ];
```

Where `X_i` (in GPU) is related to `X[ i ]` (on CPU).
Once the GPU has finished all 10000 threads. The results are downloaded back to CPU and the array `X[]` is updapted with the desired result!

**IMPORTANT:** Of course it's just a dummy example. In fact this algorithm in particular is so simple that a loop over 10000 is really not a big deal for CPU. The upload/download of data to/from GPU has a cost of time! So it must be worth!

### The answer

Thinking about all this. You can find out by yourself which kind of algorithms are better for CPU or GPU. Of course, one must always be aware about the balance of download/upload of data to/from GPU.

Comment: Thank you, I see, if threads are independent,then parallelize them,then we can use GPGPU. So the problem is judging whether the threads are independent.

Comment: Your "Non parallelizable algorithm (CPU)" is *highly* parallelizable.  This is a fundamental piece of a vector norm function and many parallel libraries implement that, including CUBLAS.   The first step is to perform `data[ i ] * data[ i ];` on every element, which is completely independent and embarassingly parallel.  The second step is to perform a classical parallel reduction.  You'll have to work much harder than that to come up with a "non-parallelizable" example.

Comment: Yes, I knew... I tried firsty to give very a dummy example... without talk about "reduction"... do you have a better example for us to illustrate here? so we can improve the answer!

Comment: @WagnerPatriota, you could try shifting the array for e.g.: `data[i] = data [i+1]`. It can be parallelized, but only with some effort

Answer (score 0):

The GPU generally has associated with it a cost to transfer data to and from the GPU.  There are some problems that can be described [that involve almost no data transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456042/parallelize-function-which-will-count-all-vectors-with-sum-equal-of-vector-eleme/19462769#19462769), but many problems start out with a data set that must be transferred to the GPU, and it is always the case that there are some results that need to be transferred back.

Therefore extremely small problems are not sensible on the GPU:

```
int C = A + B;
```

If this is the only work you have to do with `C`, `A`, and `B`, then there's not likely to be any benefit using the GPU, since the overhead and cost to transfer the data outweighs any benefit from using the GPU (and there is no benefit in this case because there is no inherent parallelism in this example).

Purely sequential problems don't benefit from using the GPU in most cases, because a single GPU thread does not execute code quicker than a modern CPU thread.  It's more difficult to make a blanket statement here, however, because most purely sequential algorithms can be recast in a parallel fashion, and even sequential algorithms can be naively parallelized if they are operating on multiple independent data elements.

Comment: a single GPU thread does not execute code quicker than a modern CPU thread. This means a lot I think. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The example "non-parallelizable" problem is quite parallelizable - especially if you do it frequently.  Sum 10,000 numbers?   First sum 5000 pairs in parallel, then the 2500 results in parallel, then the subsequent 1250 results, etc.  14 steps, faster than any uniprocessor can do it.  And if you have a flow of information, you can do this with 10,000 parallel addition operations once per "fillDataFromSomeWhereWithSomething()" operation.

Extra bonus brownie points if you can presort the numbers into plus and minus bins and add numbers of opposite and similar value;  this minimizes the accumulated roundoff error, though it does add N log N comparison operations, and a comparison is about as expensive as an addition.  OTOH, it means you can use smaller, faster adders.