# How can this combination algorithm be modified to run in parallel on a cuda enabled gpu?

Tags: c, algorithm, cuda, parallel-processing, gpu

I currently have a c program that generates all possible combinations of a character string. Please note combinations, not permutations. This is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Constants
static const char set[] = "abcd";
static const int setSize = sizeof(set) - 1;

 void brute(char* temp, int index, int max){
     //Declarations
     int i;
     for(i = 0; i < setSize; i++){
         temp[index] = set[i];
         if(index == max - 1){
                printf("%s\n", temp);
         }
         else{
              brute(temp, index + 1, max);
         }
   }
}

void length(int max_len){
   //Declarations
   char* temp = (char *) malloc(max_len + 1);
   int i;

   //Execute
   for(i = 1; i <= max_len; i++){
         memset(temp, 0, max_len + 1);
         brute(temp, 0, i);
   }
   free(temp);
}


int main(void){
   //Execute
   length(2);
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

The maximum length of the combinations can be modified; it is currently set to 2 for demonstration purposes. Given how it's currently configured, the program outputs

`a, b, c, d, aa, ab, ac, ad, ba, bb, bc, bd, ca, cb, cc...`

I've managed to translate this program into cuda:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//On-Device Memory
__constant__ char set_d[] = "adcd";
__constant__ int setSize_d = 4;

__device__ void brute(char* temp, int index, int max){
  //Declarations 
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < setSize_d; i++){
      temp[index] = set_d[i];
      if(index == max - 1){
          printf("%s\n", temp);
      }
      else{
          brute(temp, index + 1, max);
      }
  }
}


__global__ void length_d(int max_len){

      //Declarations
  char* temp = (char *) malloc(max_len + 1);
  int i;
  //Execute
  for(i = 1; i <= max_len; i++){
      memset(temp, 0, max_len+1);
      brute(temp, 0, i);
  }
  free(temp);
}


int main()
{
    //Execute
    cudaSetDevice(0);

    //Launch Kernel
    length_d<<<1, 1>>>(2);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    getchar(); //Keep this console open...
    return 0;
}
```

The cuda version of the original program is basically an exact copy of the c program (note that it is being compiled with `-arch=sm_20`. Therefore, `printf` and other host functions work in the cuda environment).

My goal is to compute combinations of `a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and other characters` of maximum lengths up to 10. That being the case, I want this program to run on my gpu.  As it is now, it does not take advantage of parallel processing - which obviously defeats the whole purpose of writing the program in cuda. However, I'm not sure how to remove the recursive nature of the program in addition to delegating the threads to a specific index or starting point.

Any constructive input is appreciated.

Also, I get an occasional warning message on successive compiles (meaning it sporadically appears): `warning : Stack size for entry function '_Z8length_di' cannot be statically determined`.

I haven't pinpointed the problem yet, but I figured I would post it in case anyone identified the cause before I can. It is being compiled in visual studio 2012.

Note: I found this to be fairly interesting. As the cuda program is now, its output to the console is periodic - meaning that it prints a few dozen combinations, pauses, prints a few dozen combinations, pauses, and so forth. I also observe this behavior in its reported gpu usage - it periodically swings from 5% to 100%.

Comment: You might be interested in the answer that @JackOLantern gave [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945347/generating-permutations-with-cuda) which computes permutations.  You might be interested in the answer I gave [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456042/parallelize-function-which-will-count-all-vectors-with-sum-equal-of-vector-eleme/19462769#19462769), which creates combinations.  The warning you're seeing is related to the recursive function call.  It's not necessarily an issue.  You should indicate the exact `nvcc` compile command that is being used to compile it.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I will definitely read that. Here's the compile command that visual studio issues: `nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2012 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin"  -I"C:\...\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\include"  -G   --keep-dir Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  " -o Debug\kernel.cu.obj "D:\...\cuda_permute\cuda_permute\kernel.cu"`

Comment: Is this an assignment for a class?

Comment: @RobertCrovella No, it's not. I've been interested in parallel computing for awhile, and I wanted to work on a project. This is part of a bruteforcer I'm writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use recursion for this.  (I wouldn't).

Using `printf` from the kernel is [problematic for large amounts of output](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#limitations); it's not really designed for that purpose.  And `printf` from the kernel eliminates any speed benefit the GPU might have.  And I assume if you're testing a large vector space like this, your goal is not to print out every combination.  Even if that were your goal, `printf` from the kernel is not the way to go.

Another issue you will run into is storage for the entire vector space you have in mind.  If you have some processing you intend to do on each vector and then you can discard it, then storage is not an issue.  But storage for a vector space of length n=10 with "digits" (elements) that have k=62 or more possible values (a..z, A..Z, 0..9, etc.)  will be huge.  It's given by k^n, so in this example that would be 62^10 different vectors.  If each digit required a byte to store it, that would be over *7 trillion gigabytes*.    So this pretty much dictates that storage of the entire vector space is out of the question.  Whatever work you're going to do, you're going to have to do it on the fly.

Given the above discussion, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456042/parallelize-function-which-will-count-all-vectors-with-sum-equal-of-vector-eleme/19462769#19462769) should have pretty much everything that you need.  The vector digits are handled as `unsigned int`, you can create whatever mapping you want between `unsigned int` and your "digits" (i.e. a..z, A..Z, 0..9, etc.)  In that example, the function that was performed on each vector was testing if the sum of the digits matched a certain value, so you could replace this line in the kernel:

```
  if (vec_sum(vec, n) == sum) atomicAdd(count, 1UL);
```

with whatever function and processing you wanted to apply to each vector generated.  You could even put a `printf` here, but for larger spaces the output will be fragmented and incomplete.

Comment: Yes, I was not planning on storing the vectors by any means. I just need to compute them and discard them. The `printf` was just to verify that the program worked properly. Thanks for your input.